# Smallest values of y for values of x

Tags: calculus

> What are the largest and smallest values of $y=x^3 - 12x + 1$ for values of $x$ in the range $-3$ to $+5$?

So I find the question a bit odd as it is stated, so I'm wondering if anyone can clear up what is meant? What I just did is:

$$y' = 3x^2 - 12$$

$$ x^2 = 4, x = \pm 2$$

$$y(2) = -15, y(-2) = 17$$

But I have a feeling that this is a misinterpretation of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is asking for the maximum and minimum of $$x^3 - 12x + 1$$ subject to the condition that $-3 \le x \le 5$. What you've done (setting the derivative to $0$) is correct for finding local extrema, but don't forget to check the endpoints - that is, find $y(5)$ and $y(-3)$ and compare.

Comment: Hmm, that seems logical, thanks.